# How to get warning for omission of let/var inside object method?

Tags: javascript, strict

New javascript programmer -- I'd like any advice on how to get warnings when I accidentally forget to include `var` or `let` inside an object method.  That is, with an object like this

```
let myObject = {
 someFunction: function (aParameterString) {
     let arr = aParameterString.split("");
     part1 = [];
     let part2 = [];
     for (let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
       //do some stuff with part1 and part2
      }
   }
}
```

is there a way to get a warning for the omission of `let` for a variable, such as `part1`in this case?  As I understand it, if I omit it, the variable is created on the object?  I thought using "strict mode" would warn me, but my IDE (Webstorm) is not issuing any indication of the problem, and when I run the code in Node, there's no warning. Forgive me if I'm missing the obvious, or otherwise clueless --  I'd like to catch errors like this in future.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you really run in strict mode (your code doesn't seem to use it?), and that assignment runs without an exception, that means that you already declared a (global?) variable `part1` somewhere in scope.

Comment: You can verify if you've [configured a JavaScript linter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/linters.html).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if strict mode isn't throwing for an undeclared ref, I'm not sure how the linter is going to help.

Comment: Ah, I need to put it in the code as well?  I thought it was an IDE setting (as it seems to be in the Webstorm settings).  Thanks for the info.  As an aside, I cannot for the life of me understand why people down-vote honest questions.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's the whole point of linters: call you attention about potential bugs.

Comment: @Cerulean not the DV, but this question is borderline on acceptability. It could arguably be closed as a typo (forgot to include 'use strict'), opinion based (what's the best linter), or no MVCE (you do not provide sufficient code to repro).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález in the OP's case (forgot 'use strict') it would definitely have caught the leaked global, and I'm not saying that it's a bad idea (it's a good one!) but I don't see how a linter would catch e.g. the situation described by Bergi.

Comment: It was that I needed to include "use strict" in the code itself.  I had thought that the IDE itself would handle that (there is a section dealing with whether to "use strict" or not, or something along those lines, deep within the Webstorm preferences).  Beginner's problem, easy solution.    I appreciate the help from those who helped.

Comment: @JaredSmith -- I don't really understand why it wouldn't be acceptable. It was a beginner's mistake (omitting the code "use strict").  My error was in trusting the IDE to do the checking for me (there's an unchecked check box in the Webstorm IDE that asks whether "Non-strict mode is used" -- it's unchecked, so I thought the IDE was checking for me.)  I've programmed for a long time, but am learning javascript.  Not sure that dumb errors should be penalised if the questions are asked after some research, i.e. one isn't just being lazy…

Comment: @Cerulean it was just a downvote. Don't take it personally. As for closing, as I said it's borderline: one of the close reasons is typo/no longer able to reproduce, and your question falls into that category. Up to the judgement of the people with sufficient rep. But note that at least three of us (Alvaro, Bergi, myself) saw your question and none of us voted to close it.

Comment: No problem.  It's just that down-voting has always seemed to me a bit inhibitory for those (of us) who are wandering (somewhat) lost in the wilderness.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include "use strict" in the code itself.  The IDE does not do checking otherwise.

Comment: Understand why, the IDE generates syntax highlighting/error messages/autocompletion by parsing your code, and strict and non-strict are parsed differently. This also plays into why you have to declare module scripts as `<script type="module">` so the browser knows which way to parse your code.